# jQuery selector for second column in HTML table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

The aim of my code is to add the data from the selected HTML table row to the JavaScript array, and remove it if the row is unselected.

https://jsfiddle.net/nicktry/h1636ram/

I have two problems at the moment:

1. The CSS Style is not being applied on the 1st click
2. I can't get the jQuery selector correct to add/remove the table data to the array.

   ```
   $('table tbody tr').click(function(event) {
               if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
                   $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
               }
               $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) {
                   if($(this).is(":checked")){
                       $(this).closest('tr').addClass("selected_row");
                       addJob(document.getElementById('jobs'), $(this).closest('tr td:nth-child(2)').text());  
                   }else{
                       $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("selected_row");
                       removeJob(document.getElementById('jobs'), $(this).closest('tr td:nth-child(2)').text());
                   }
               });
           });
   ```

The wisdom of the stackoverflow community would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have two events inside each other.

Move this

```
 $("input[type='checkbox']").not('#check_all').change(function (e) {

 });
```

outside of

```
 $('table tbody tr').click(function(event) { 

 });
```

Change this

```
$(this).closest('tr td:nth-child(2)').text()
```

to this

```
 $(this).parent().next().text()
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/h1636ram/9/

Comment: Thank you. I adjusted your code slightly and it is now working exactly as I wanted. https://jsfiddle.net/nicktry/h1636ram/10/